# "2.4GHz RF" used in some LED lighting products: what protocol is it?

Tags: led, rf, lighting

There are a number of LED light control devices about, which boast a "2.4G RF" wireless protocl, which is neither WiFi, Zigbee, nor anything else.

I was wondering if someone could shed some light which protocol is used, as it seems to be at least somewhat open.

Here's one of them:

[image: 2.4G RF LED controller]

I don't want to name-drop any manufacturer, but there seems to be more than one using this protocol.

Here's a remote control by a different manufacturer, that is compatible with the previous product:

[image: 2.4G RF remote control]

So there seems to be at least some form of (de-facto ?) standardization going on, or at least some sort of interoperability between some of them.

There are also these super cheap devices, which seem to be on the same protocol:

[image: cheap 2.4G RF receiver / LED controller]

This product also claims it's "2.4G RF compatible".

I'm primarily interested in finding a USB or serial interface.
I.e. I'd want a way to control these light controllers with a PC, however I can only find devices which act as "WiFi Gateway" and require an app and an online-service to work. It contains both a "2.4G RF" and a WiFi radio inside, so it'll show up in a local network, and talks to some sort of centralized cloud service. The app then controls this device through the cloud, using the local gateway (I'll keep my opinions on this to myself for now).

I found devices like these:

[image: 2.4G RF to SPI module]

By several manufacturers, which all boast a "2.4GHz RF" capability, withouth going further into detail, apart from sometimes saying they use FSK and/or GMSK modulation, and an SPI interface for wired communication.
However I'm not sure if I'd be able to control the previously mentioned devices.

I also found a bunch other "gateways" for the rather mysterious "2.4G RF" protocol, for instance bridging with Zigbee, etc.

As a first step I'd just some clarification what this is actually, and then perhaps some pointer on how to access it through USB, Serial, etc. as I'd want some programmatic control, rather than an app, etc. Perhaps someone else has embarked on a similar endeavor which I wasn't able to find, etc.

The home automation realm, seems to be rather saturated with a plethora of different, competing protocols, etc. this "2.4G RF" thing, seems to be yet another one, which also isn't as widely used, I suppose. I'm not looking for a practical solution for an installation, etc. I'm mainly interested in it from a technological curiosity standpoint. I'd like to both be able to read the remote controls used in those systems, and also be able to control the receivers, used for controlling LED strips, etc.
I have trouble figuring out a proper name for this protocol. Just looking for "2.4G RF" yields a bajillion false positive results, as it's just one of the many ISM bands, but also WiFi, Zigbee, and a bunch other...

Comment: Almost all of these "2.4 GHz RF" gadgets have their own custom, non-standard and incompatible protocols using simple modulation. Many are probably very similar or identical because of the common underlying chipsets used... My recommendation is to reverse engineer the protocol by capturing the traffic using a Software-Defined Radio receiver with 2.4 GHz coverage. Common modulations like FSK and OOK are trivial to decode, e.g. [*Hacking IoT RF communications with GNU Radio (H.Boeglen)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Oty02juNrY) I did something similar with my 433 MHz remote control.

Comment: It could also be WiFi, Zigbee or Bluetooth. They are all used for light control.

Comment: Apart from capturing and replaying the traffic via an SDR, another way of creating a remote control of devices with non-standard protocol and an external transceiver IC is to identify the RFIC part number used, capture the SPI/I2C bus traffic using a logic analyzer to find the chip's configuration, then your can build your own circuit board with the same IC (but it would work for only one device, sometimes the RFIC may have an integrated microcontroller core, so logic analyzer is of no use, firmware readout is also often disabled).

Comment: There were several systems that just used the baseband signal from an infrared remote, but modulated on top of 2.4 GHz instead of IR.

Comment: There are various RFIC that come with custom 2.4GHz technologies. There are many reasons why you wouldn't want your product to use any of the common, standardized technologies - for example they have non-existing real-time performance and are entirely unsuitable for real-time systems. But 2.4GHz is a convenient band since it's about the only radio band available world-wide.

Comment: @KevinWhite those aren't Zigbee, WiFi, nor bluetooth. It is "something else", hence me being interested in it. I checked the devices I have for those protocols. Also some manufacturers are offering gateway devices, like Zigbee <-> "2.4G", etc.

Comment: @比尔盖子 OK, that was my second step. I was under the impression the protocol is somewhat wider spread, as I have three cheap products (an LED controller, a remote control, and a "3-in-1" device (CCT controller receiving commands from Zigbee and "2.4G"), all purchased at different times, and from different sources, from different brands - they all work well together.

Comment: The RF IC is almost certainly an NRF24L01 - web search that and you'll get a zillion hits. 2.4 GHz ISM. 1 or 2 Mbps. Proprietary protocol BUT many many libraries for it. || They can also do standard Bluetooth, but seem never to be used that way.